# python byte to int[] from socket.recv

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I'm writing my own DNS Query with the following code in `python 2.7`

```
import socket

domain = 'example.com'
UDP_IP = "8.8.8.8"
UDP_PORT = 53

packet = [88, 89, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for part in domain.split('.'):
    packet.append(len(part))
    for char in list(part):
        packet.append(ord(char))

packet += [0, 0, 15, 0, 1]

print packet

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(bytearray(packet), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()

print repr(data)
```

which prints out the following:

```
[88, 89, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 3, 99, 111, 109, 0, 0, 15, 0, 1]
'XY\x81\x80\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x07example\x03com\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x01\xc0\x0c\x00\x06\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01z\x00-\x03sns\x03dns\x05icann\x03org\x00\x03noc\xc0-xHoU\x00\x00\x1c \x00\x00\x0e\x10\x00\x12u\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x10'
```

but how do I convert the bytes returned (which seems to come in as a string) back into an `int[]`?

The code in C# looks like the following:

```
byte[] recv = udpclient.Receive(IPEndPoint);

int[] resp = new int[recv.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < resp.Length; i++)
    resp[i] = Convert.ToInt32(recv[i]);
```

How it looks in my IDE (pyCharm)
[image]

Comment: What is an `int[]` in Python?

Comment: int[] = integer list eg. int_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is receiving the bytes from the socket and converting each byte into an int

Comment: Ugh. I think in Python 2 you'll need something like `map(ord, data)`. In Python 3, `bytes` objects act like arrays of ints limited to 256

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension (see: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) would seem to be the correct course of action, to "convert":

```
data = [ord(i) for i in data]
```

Or just do that upon receiving from the socket:

```
data = [ord(i) for i in sock.recv(1024)]
```